# Why GDB not showing address of the function causing segfault

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

main();

return 0;
}
```

Gives segmentation fault (core dumped). Also gdb with core gives the following:

```
warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff653ca000
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  main () at mainrecurs.c:6
6   main();
```

My question is why it is not showing the address of the function i.e main. Normally it shows the address also.

Running on Ubuntu 12.04, compiling with gcc

**UPDATE**

```
(gdb) info reg
rax            0x7fee4d32d568   140661474121064
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x4004d0 4195536
rdx            0x7fff8aba4718   140735520851736
rsi            0x7fff8aba4708   140735520851720
rdi            0x1  1
rbp            0x7fff8a3a6000   0x7fff8a3a6000
rsp            0x7fff8a3a6000   0x7fff8a3a6000
r8             0x400560 4195680
r9             0x7fee4d340740   140661474199360
r10            0x7fff8aba4480   140735520851072
r11            0x7fee4cf92680   140661470340736
r12            0x4003d0 4195280
r13            0x7fff8aba4700   140735520851712
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x4004b8 0x4004b8 <main+4>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
gs             0x0  0
```

**UPDATE2**

when I compiled using gcc without -g option. I am getting following with the gdb:

```
Reading symbols from /home/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 2121]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fffabb90000
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004004b8 in main ()
```

Now the address is visible, but why without debugging option it is giving address?  The address is the same as above shown in `print reg`

Comment: Did you compile with debug symbols?

Comment: I compiled like this: gcc -g recursmain.c

Comment: Which is where the error is. The segfault occurring looks like a stack overflow, you are recursively calling `main()`.

Comment: My gdb shows me the address just fine.  Have you tried running `print $rip` or `info reg` to print out the instruction pointer?

Comment: (gdb) print $rip gives
$1 = (void (*)()) 0x4004b8 <main+4>

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, this:

```
#0  main () at mainrecurs.c:6
6   main();
```

is **exactly** what you are looking for. A C file, a (correct) line number, and the function where it occurred.

This segfault is a stack overflow, because you recursively call `main()`.

Comment: Although fully correct, this does not answer the OP's question regarding why gdb does not print the **address** where the error occurrred.

Comment: That's because it is a stack overflow and not a protection fault.

Comment: I am not looking for the line number , I am looking for the address of the function

Comment: @user2799508 I understand. Apparently `gdb` has a different behaviour for stack overflow than for protection faults.

Comment: @BartFriederichs OK. BTW when stackoverflow happens why would the address not print?

Comment: @BartFriederichs The address is visible if I compile without debugging info, i,e without -g option , as you can see in my UPDATED2 above

Comment: @user2799508 I guess `gdb` decides that debugging with source code is easier than with addresses (I kinda agree).

Answer (score 0):

You will get warning something like below if you give attention to warnings:

> warning C4717: 'main' : recursive on all control paths, function will
>   cause runtime stack overflow

And gdb will give you line number where it failed.

> 6   main();

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question regarding why gdb does not print the **address** where the error occurrred.